# ORACLE SQL - SUM two queries together and a single value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, pivot

i have looked for a simple example to sum two queries together and get a final output as a single value. I have set up a simple query below to use as an example.

```
SELECT Count (banana)
FROM FRUIT_BASKET
WHERE CONDITION = 'ROTTEN'
/ -- THEN DIVIDE THIS NUMBER BY
SELECT Count (banana)
FROM FRUIT_BASKET
* 100 -- TO GET A PERCENTAGE
```

Any help will be great thankyou all

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CONDITION = 'ROTTEN' THEN banana END) * 100 / COUNT(banana)
FROM FRUIT_BASKET
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    count(case when condition = 'ROTTEN' then banana end)
    / count(banana) * 100
from fruit_basket
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using `AVG()` for this:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN Condition = 'Rotten' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM FRUIT_BASKET
WHERE banana IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This is clean. Side note: oracle does not do integer division (as you know), so no need for for the decimal part in `100.0`.

Comment: @GMB . . . That is just a habit so I don't have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely consider the **divide by zero** scenario in such case.

So better to use `avg` aggregate function as suggested by gordon or handle **divide by zero** scenario by yourself as following:

> ```
> select
>     count(case when condition = 'ROTTEN' then banana end)
>     / decode(count(banana),0,1) * 100
> from fruit_basket
> ```

Cheers!!